# How do I register an inquirer.js plugin for a yeoman generator prompt?

Tags: node.js, code-generation, yeoman, yeoman-generator, inquirerjs

When authoring a yeoman generator, I'd like to use the 'autocomplete' plugin for inquirer (https://github.com/mokkabonna/inquirer-autocomplete-prompt) in one of my prompts.  I can't seem to find anything in the docs that says how to register this plugin with inquirer from within the yeoman generator.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

found the answer :

```
module.exports = class extends Generator {
  initializing() {
    this.env.adapter.promptModule.registerPrompt("autocomplete", require("inquirer-autocomplete-prompt"));
  }
}
```